# How to configure log4j 2 to asynchonous mode programmatically?

Tags: java, log4j2

I've found several examples of programmatic configuration, but none of those mention asynchronous logging.
How can I configure log4j 2 to make all loggers asynchronous?
Just to be clear: I can't make it by setting the System property. What I need is something like this: [How to configure log4j 2.x purely programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30881990/how-to-configure-log4j-2-x-purely-programmatically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't use system property and `log4j2.component.properties` file. You can try the `ConfigurationFactory.setConfigurationFactory` method.

Here's a brief example:

**Log4j2.java**

```
public class Log4j2 {

  static {
    ConfigurationFactory.setConfigurationFactory(new CustomConfigurationFactory()); // This must be called before any other calls to Log4j
  }

  private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    logger.info("hello");
  }
}
```

**CustomConfigurationFactory.java**

```
@Plugin(name = "CustomConfigurationFactory", category = ConfigurationFactory.CATEGORY)
@Order(50)
public class CustomConfigurationFactory extends ConfigurationFactory {

  private static Configuration createConfiguration(final String name, ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder) {
    builder.setConfigurationName(name);

    AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("Stdout", "CONSOLE").
        addAttribute("target", ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
    appenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").
        addAttribute("pattern", "%level: %msg%n"));
    builder.add(appenderBuilder);

    RootLoggerComponentBuilder rootLoggerBuilder = builder.newAsyncRootLogger(Level.DEBUG); // use newAsyncRootLogger instead of newRootLogger 
    rootLoggerBuilder.add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout"));

    builder.add(rootLoggerBuilder);
    return builder.build();
  }

  @Override
  public Configuration getConfiguration(final LoggerContext loggerContext, final ConfigurationSource source) {
    return getConfiguration(loggerContext, source.toString(), null);
  }

  @Override
  public Configuration getConfiguration(final LoggerContext loggerContext, final String name, final URI configLocation) {
    ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = newConfigurationBuilder();
    return createConfiguration(name, builder);
  }

  @Override
  protected String[] getSupportedTypes() {
    return new String[]{"*"};
  }
}
```

Hope this helps :-)