# java - How to configure the output encoding in log4j 2.x programmatically?

Tags: java, character-encoding, log4j2

There are other questions about [configuring programmatically log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30881990/how-to-configure-log4j-2-x-purely-programmatically), but I coun't find a way to configure the log output encoding?

Comment: Perhaps a custom appender can help

Comment: Declarative `<PatternLayout charset="UTF-8" ....`; so one has to go from FileAppender to its layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't solve it programatically. My solution was to execute the java interpreter with this option:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8
```

Answer (score 0):

In log4j one would do the following, so I assume too for log4j2:

```
  Logger hlogger = Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate.stat");
  SimpleLayout layout = new SimpleLayout();
  ConsoleAppender consoleAppender = new ConsoleAppender(layout);
  consoleAppender.setEncoding("UTF-8");
  hlogger.addAppender(consoleAppender);
  hlogger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
```