# OutputStream write(int b) method: special characters encoding

Tags: encoding, char, jtextarea, outputstream

I'm not able to solve my problem with writing special characters `ěščřžýáíé` using method `write(int b)` from `OutputStream` class. I'm using this class to redirect console output to `JTextArea`.

```
class CustomOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    private JTextArea textArea;

    CustomOutputStream(JTextArea textArea) {
        this.textArea = textArea;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) {
        textArea.append(String.valueOf((char) b));
        // scrolls the text area to the end of data
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
    }
}
```

It works fine for standard characters. For characters `ěščřžýáíé` it prints unreadable characters.

[image]

I don't know how to set character encoding or how to solve this by other way.

Thank you, J.

Answer (score 0):

You convert `b` which was an `int` to `char` type, so you lose most of the information. And you are not interpreting the `b` as unicode code point.

```
textArea.append(Character.toChars​(b))
```

If your original text is not Unicode, you may decode it.

Comment: Hi,

I tried your solution, but I got `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` at `java.lang.Character.toChars`.

Comment: Could you do `textArea.append(String.valueOf(b)); textArea.append("-")`? Or show how do you call `write`? Maybe you screw encoding at call, or from start, it is not an unicode string.

Comment: I'm using log4j2 for logging to console and file - there are all characters fine. In my GUI application, I redirected output from console to `PrintStream` by `System.setOut(printStream);`. So method `write()` is called automatically when something is logged to console.

Result for `ěščřžýáíé` if `textArea.append(String.valueOf(b)); textArea.append(".")` is `.ￄ.ﾛ.ￅ.ﾡ.ￄ.ﾍ.ￅ.ﾙ.ￅ.ﾾ.ￃ.ﾽ.ￃ.ﾡ.ￃ.ﾭ.ￃ.ﾩ.`

Comment: It seems that logs are no more Unicode characters (if you are on windows: Windows console usually uses non-unicode encodings). Try something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48446009/java-how-to-configure-the-output-encoding-in-log4j-2-x-programmatically  . UTF-16 is the expected encoding.