# Replace log4j2 configuration at runtime

Tags: java, log4j2

I have a war application with a log4j2.properties file in it. Once the service is starting, I would like to change this default logging configuration programmatically from an external .properties file.

I use code similar than that

```java
String log4jConfigFile = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "log4j2.xml";
ConfigurationSource source = new ConfigurationSource(new FileInputStream(log4jConfigFile));
Configurator.initialize(null, source);
```

But it seems that once the log context is initialized, it can not be changed, at least in that manner.
Is there any way to replace current log configuration from an external lo4j2.properties at runtime, and once the log context was just initialized?

Comment: Strange, it work in my case, can you try printing something after initialized. LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeClass.class).info("load log4j2 from: {}", path);

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42118587/139985) in the duplink explains what you need to do to change the configuration dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as you already noticed the `Configurator.initialize` methods work only before the first initialization of the `LoggerContext`.

Afterwards you need to use the [`Configurator.reconfigure`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/Configurator.html#reconfigure-java.net.URI-) methods:

```java
final Path log4jConfigPath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "log4j2.xml");
Configurator.reconfigure(log4jConfigPath.toUri())
```

By the way, the `Configurator.reconfigure` methods work also before the first initialization of the `LoggerContext`.

Comment: So it doesn't work for me. Is there any way to reconfigure from a properties file after the first initialization of the LoggerContext. I would like to have a default properties file inside the war file, and check after the initialization if there is an external properties file and reconfigure it again. Or is there any annotation "before-log-context-initialization" to programmatically check if an external file exists and reconfigure the LoggerContext before its initialization?

Comment: Add `-Dlog4j2.debug=true` to your JVM arguments to check why the reconfiguration does not occur (the debug output will appear on the standard error). BTW: the behavior you are seeking does not require code: see the [`log4j2.configurationFile`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#SystemProperties) property (which can be set in several ways).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally I solved it putting the log4j2.component.properties file in the WAR classpath, setting the log4j2.configurationFile property. It can be set a list of log4j2 properties files, it seems that the last file it finds in the list, is the configuration that is kept, for me is a little bit strange, but anyway, it works.